# Python CSV to JSON creating an error with symbols for example £

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv, utf-8

I'm having a problem with reading/using csv files that have symbols in them in this case it's the symbol `£`

Running the following code:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("A", "B", "C")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    print row
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

On the data

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,
10:00,LOC,1-10,£500.00,4+,DATA,
10:00,LOC,1-10,£500.00,2+,MORE,
10:10,LOC2,1-1,£9000,39+,DATA,
10:10,LOC2,1-3,£500,22+,MORE,
10:10,LOC2,1-5,£500,11+,DATA,
```

Prints:

```
{'A': 'A', None: ['D', 'E', 'F', ''], 'C': 'C', 'B': 'B'}
{'A': '10:00', None: ['\xa3500.00', '4+', 'DATA', ''], 'C': '1-10', 'B': 'LOC'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\testscript.py", line 12, in <module>
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 189, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 313, in _iterencode_list
    yield buf + _encoder(value)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I do eventually want to parse columns that have symbols like the `£` pound sign through the json module outputting them into the json file.

How can I get around this problem so that that the error doesn't come up...

#### Using chfw's code and getting around `\u00a`

```
# -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-

import csv
import json
import codecs
import StringIO

fieldnames = ("A", "B", "C")

### code insertion start ###
class Iterator(object):
    def next(self):
        return type(self).__next__(self)

class UTF8Recorder(Iterator):
    """
    Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8.
    """
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):       
        return next(self.reader).encode('utf-8')
### code insertion stop ###

with open('DATA.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(UTF8Recorder(csvfile, 'iso-8859-1'), fieldnames)

    stored_output = StringIO.StringIO()

    for row in reader:
        print row
        json.dump(row, stored_output)
        stored_output.write('\n')

    contents = stored_output.getvalue().strip()

    with open('DATA.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
        jsonfile.write(contents.replace("\u00a", "£"))
```

Comment: Try opening with `rb` instead of `r` mode?  And `wb` of course.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've already tried that and it doesn't work either :/

Comment: What platform?  I'm using Python 2.7 on Linux and your code works fine.

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate, 64bit

Comment: Is `file.csv` encoded in UTF-8?  I would guess it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information on [the encoding of pound sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm). I guess you had "iso-8859-1". Hence my solution is:

```
import csv
import json
import codecs

csvfile = open('utf.csv', 'rb')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("A", "B", "C")

### code insertion start ###
class Iterator(object):
    def next(self):
        return type(self).__next__(self)

class UTF8Recorder(Iterator):
    """
    Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8.
    """
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):       
        return next(self.reader).encode('utf-8')
### code insertion stop ###
reader = csv.DictReader(UTF8Recorder(csvfile, 'iso-8859-1'), fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    print row
    jsonfile.write(row.__repr__()) # json.dump(row, jsonfile), <- updated
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

If the encoding is not 'iso-8859-1', please replace the one that you know in the UTF8Recorder argument.

Comment: That seems to work kinda, but the £ symbols come out as `\u00a` I've created a hacky workaround, check my original post for a copy of it.